# Why is a large positive number smaller than 0?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, momentjs

So, I am writing a function to get the closest date of today within a given array by comparing the difference in minutes. I have this code:

```
const getSelectedDate = () => {
    const today = moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    const dates = data.data;
    let minDiff = null;
    let closestDate = dates[0].startDate;
    dates.map((item) => {
        const diff = Math.abs(moment(today).diff(moment(item.startDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD'), 'minutes', true));
        console.log('Diff: ' + diff + ' for date: ' +  item.startDate + ' with minDiff: ' + minDiff);
        if(!minDiff || diff < minDiff) {
            minDiff = diff;
            closestDate = item.startDate;
        }
    });
    return closestDate;
}
```

The problem is that it returns the closest date from 16-04-2021 as 13-04-2021 and not the 16-04-2021 index.

Example output:

```
Diff: 5760 for date: 2021-04-12T16:00:00 with minDiff: null
Diff: 0 for date: 2021-04-16T16:00:00 with minDiff: 5760
Diff: 4320 for date: 2021-04-13T16:00:00 with minDiff: 0
Diff: 17280 for date: 2021-04-28T16:00:00 with minDiff: 4320
2021-04-13T16:00:00
```

How is 0 defined while comparing?

Comment: Tip: Don't use `map` for iterating, use `forEach`.

Comment: I'm not sure where you're drawing that conclusion about "large positive number smaller than 0". You've sort of sabotaged yourself here by having `minDiff == 0` which means `!minDiff` is true. Maybe you mean `minDiff != null || ...`

Comment: Instead of all this cruft you might want to just sort the array (e.g. `_.sortBy(dates, 'startDate')` in lodash) and pick off either the first or last entry.

Comment: tip: you can use reduce in this case so you do not need to define let closestDate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> if(!minDiff || diff < minDiff) {
> ```

So if the minDiff is **zero**

> ```
>    minDiff = diff;
> ```

Then it is replaced by the new difference

---

You probably want to test `minDiff === null` instead of testing it for non-truthiness.

Comment: Gotcha! changing the if statement to if(minDiff === null || diff < minDiff) did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your test for minDiff not being set:

```js
    if(!minDiff || diff < minDiff && minDiff !== 0) {...
```

The first part of the test `!minDiff` will return `true` if minDiff has value `0`

You should strictly test for null instead:

```js
    if(minDiff === null || diff < minDiff) {...
```